# Some flash videos do not play

Tags: video, flash, flash-player

I'm on a Mac and use mainly Firefox 8, but the problem that I'll describe happens with Chrome and Safari as well.

Basically, I can play most Flash content, including ads, games and videos, but there are some specific videos that do not play at all (the flash portion of the page stays black). For an example of such video, see [this page](http://g1.globo.com/videos/sao-paulo/v/capotamento-deixa-tres-pessoas-da-mesma-familia-feridas-na-zona-sul-de-sao-paulo/1697930/) (brazilian news site).

I have the latest version of Flash player and I was able to play the video using the URL of the player concatenated with the flashVars that I got from the source code os the page.

Any ideas on what's causing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like some sort of ad-blocker is interfering (false-positive).

- Are you using an ad-blocking browser-extension? > If so, try adding the site to the exceptions.
- Are you using the HOSTS file for ad-blocking? > If so, you’ll need to figure out what domain(s) to remove from it.
- Are you using some other security software with ad-blocking features? > If so, try disabling it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already tested with a clean browser (no blockers of any kind). As I said, I can see ads normally in the site, just the videos that won't play automatically. I've posted in the Adobe Forum. Sadly there was no answer. I'm giving up on this :(

Comment: Like I said, it might not be the browser; it could be getting blocked in the HOSTS file or other security software (eg firewall, anti-virus, router, etc.) You have to understand that providers and CDNs change their hosts and IPs often, so what was blocked or not blocked last week may end up changing this week, so you (or the software) cannot simply set one set of rules and leave it for all time; they have to be updated regularly.

Comment: Thanks again. There's nothing blocking the content. If I go to the source code of the page containing the Flash video, copy the URL of the video and concatenate the flashVars attribute, the video plays fine.

Comment: Ah, okay, then it is JavaScript that is getting tripped up. Try a different browser to verify.

Comment: Ah, okay; that is important information. It is probably JavaScript that is getting tripped up. Try a different browser to verify.